# Capitalized the first letter of the name in vba

Tags: vba, excel

Can you help me to my problem , I want to happen in my program is that when you type a name to textbox in userform like this "Vincent" it will pass to the sheet in the same manner

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    If cmdAdd.Caption = "ADD" Then
        txtName.Enabled = True: cboAge.Enabled = True:
        cmdAdd.Caption = "SAVE": cmdClose.Caption = "CANCEL"
        txtName.SetFocus
    Else
        If txtName.Text = "" Or cboAge.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox "Required field(s) missing!", vbCritical, "Message"
        Else
            For i = 2 To Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                If LCase(txtName.Text) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value And _
                cboAge.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value Then
                    MsgBox "Record already exist!", vbExclamation, "Message"
                    Call UserForm_Activate
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Next i

            r = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Sheet1.Cells(r, 1).Value = (txtName.Text)
            Sheet1.Cells(r, 2).Value = cboAge.Text
            r = 0
            MsgBox "One record saved!", vbInformation, "Message"
            Call UserForm_Activate
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

this is the code can you help me ..thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `StrConv` to convert to Propercase. See this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264628.aspx) Link

```
Debug.Print StrConv(Textbox1.Text, vbProperCase)
```

For example (From your code)

```
Sheet1.Cells(r, 1).Value = StrConv(txtName.Text, vbProperCase)
```